# Systemctl status shows Succeeded, but service is inactive

Tags: linux, bash, debian, systemd, systemctl

I have this simple `/etc/systemd/system/test.service` file

```
[Unit]
Description=SkriptA
After=network.target auditd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i run `systemctl start test.service` and then `systemctl status test.service` It shows that serivce succeeded but is inacitve, please why is this?

```
● test1.service - SkriptA
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test1.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 05 12:17:55 hro0078 systemd[1]: Started SkriptA.
Mar 05 12:17:55 hro0078 systemd[1]: test1.service: Succeeded.
```

The ExecStart script is simple as service

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo Hi > /tmp/test1
date >> /tmp/test1
```

I use: `Linux version 4.19.0-13-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28)`

Comment: Meaning of each systemctl status is in no way specific to programming; rather of interest to all users and computer admins of systemctl.  Try on Unix & Linux Stackexchange or Superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program was started successfully and it terminated directly.

To have your service `active`, it needs to keep running. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]; do
    echo Hi > /tmp/test1
    date >> /tmp/test1
    sleep 60
done
```